# Test hypotheses to compare income between internet users and others

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

> Of the Internet users, 493 reported having revenues of less than $50,000 while 378 earned 50,000 or more. The corresponding numbers for those who did not use the internet to prepare for their trip were 477 and 200. Test hypotheses to compare income between internet users and others and give a 95% confidence interval for the difference between the two proportions.

Here, I don't know what statistical test should I use?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe best to test proportions.

Comment: which means I should compare the proportions of people with income < 50k between 2 groups?